# Mailman : Unable to reset list admin password?

Tags: mailman

I was trying to reset a mailman list admin password using the change_pw command:

```
$ %MYMAILMANBINS%/change_pw -l mylist
```

I got a message with the new password and receive and email as the owner of the list with this new password.However, I am unable to log in on the web interface.

So:

- either the password was not updated properly
- or there is another problem with the mailman installation (everything is working fine though: the mailing-lists themselves, the "personnal" login for a specific user of a list, ...)

Thanks for any idea to solve that. I am maybe missing something obvious...